# Site tour code tips not showing

Tags: jquery

I'm using code which was originally written for an earlier version of jquery which i think I've updated correctly but nothing showing... I need it to work with 1.8.3

I've set up a fiddle as prob easier that way to see it in action: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/v4cAX/)

This is where original code came from: [Tour code](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/)

Any ideas?

Here's the jquery:

```
$(function() {
            /*
            the json config obj.
            name: the class given to the element where you want the tooltip to appear
            bgcolor: the background color of the tooltip
            color: the color of the tooltip text
            text: the text inside the tooltip
            time: if automatic tour, then this is the time in ms for this step
            position: the position of the tip. Possible values are
                TL  top left
                TR  top right
                BL  bottom left
                BR  bottom right
                LT  left top
                LB  left bottom
                RT  right top
                RB  right bottom
                T   top
                R   right
                B   bottom
                L   left
             */
            var config = [
                {
                    "name"      : "tut10",
                    "bgcolor"   : "black",
                    "color"     : "white",
                    "position"  : "TL",
                    "text"      : "You can create a tour to explain the functioning of your app",
                    "time"      : 5000
                },
                {
                    "name"      : "tut20",
                    "bgcolor"   : "black",
                    "color"     : "white",
                    "text"      : "Give a class to the points of your walkthrough",
                    "position"  : "BL",
                    "time"      : 5000
                }

            ],
            //define if steps should change automatically
            autoplay    = false,
            //timeout for the step
            showtime,
            //current step of the tour
            step        = 0,
            //total number of steps
            total_steps = config.length;

            //show the tour controls
            showControls();

            /*
            we can restart or stop the tour,
            and also navigate through the steps
             */
            $('#activatetour').live('click',startTour);
            $('#canceltour').live('click',endTour);
            $('#endtour').live('click',endTour);
            $('#restarttour').live('click',restartTour);
            $('#nextstep').live('click',nextStep);
            $('#prevstep').live('click',prevStep);

            function startTour(){
                $('#activatetour').remove();
                $('#endtour,#restarttour').show();
                if(!autoplay && total_steps > 1)
                    $('#nextstep').show();
                showOverlay();
                nextStep();
            }

            function nextStep(){
                if(!autoplay){
                    if(step > 0)
                        $('#prevstep').show();
                    else
                        $('#prevstep').hide();
                    if(step == total_steps-1)
                        $('#nextstep').hide();
                    else
                        $('#nextstep').show();  
                }   
                if(step >= total_steps){
                    //if last step then end tour
                    endTour();
                    return false;
                }
                ++step;
                showTooltip();
            }

            function prevStep(){
                if(!autoplay){
                    if(step > 2)
                        $('#prevstep').show();
                    else
                        $('#prevstep').hide();
                    if(step == total_steps)
                        $('#nextstep').show();
                }       
                if(step <= 1)
                    return false;
                --step;
                showTooltip();
            }

            function endTour(){
                step = 0;
                if(autoplay) clearTimeout(showtime);
                removeTooltip();
                hideControls();
                hideOverlay();
            }

            function restartTour(){
                step = 0;
                if(autoplay) clearTimeout(showtime);
                nextStep();
            }

            function showTooltip(){
                //remove current tooltip
                removeTooltip();

                var step_config     = config[step-1];
                var $elem           = $('.' + step_config.name);

                if(autoplay)
                    showtime    = setTimeout(nextStep,step_config.time);

                var bgcolor         = step_config.bgcolor;
                var color           = step_config.color;

                var $tooltip = $('',{
                    id : 'tour_tooltip',
                    class : 'tooltip',
                    html : '+step_config.text+'
                    }).css({
                    'display' : 'none',
                    'background-color' : bgcolor,
                    'color' : color
                });

                //position the tooltip correctly:

                //the css properties the tooltip should have
                var properties      = {};

                var tip_position    = step_config.position;

                //append the tooltip but hide it
                $('BODY').prepend($tooltip);

                //get some info of the element
                var e_w             = $elem.outerWidth();
                var e_h             = $elem.outerHeight();
                var e_l             = $elem.offset().left;
                var e_t             = $elem.offset().top;


                switch(tip_position){
                    case 'TL'   :
                        properties = {
                            'left'  : e_l,
                            'top'   : e_t + e_h + 'px'
                        };
                        $tooltip.find('span.tooltip_arrow').addClass('tooltip_arrow_TL');
                        break;
                    case 'TR'   :
                        properties = {
                            'left'  : e_l + e_w - $tooltip.width() + 'px',
                            'top'   : e_t + e_h + 'px'
                        };
                        $tooltip.find('span.tooltip_arrow').addClass('tooltip_arrow_TR');
                        break;
                    case 'BL'   :
                        properties = {
                            'left'  : e_l + 'px',
                            'top'   : e_t - $tooltip.height() + 'px'
                        };
                        $tooltip.find('span.tooltip_arrow').addClass('tooltip_arrow_BL');
                        break;
                    case 'BR'   :
                        properties = {
                            'left'  : e_l + e_w - $tooltip.width() + 'px',
                            'top'   : e_t - $tooltip.height() + 'px'
                        };
                        $tooltip.find('span.tooltip_arrow').addClass('tooltip_arrow_BR');
                        break;
                    case 'LT'   :
                        properties = {
                            'left'  : e_l + e_w + 'px',
                            'top'   : e_t + 'px'
                        };
                        $tooltip.find('span.tooltip_arrow').addClass('tooltip_arrow_LT');
                        break;
                    case 'LB'   :
                        properties = {
                            'left'  : e_l + e_w + 'px',
                            'top'   : e_t + e_h - $tooltip.height() + 'px'
                        };
                        $tooltip.find('span.tooltip_arrow').addClass('tooltip_arrow_LB');
                        break;
                    case 'RT'   :
                        properties = {
                            'left'  : e_l - $tooltip.width() + 'px',
                            'top'   : e_t + 'px'
                        };
                        $tooltip.find('span.tooltip_arrow').addClass('tooltip_arrow_RT');
                        break;
                    case 'RB'   :
                        properties = {
                            'left'  : e_l - $tooltip.width() + 'px',
                            'top'   : e_t + e_h - $tooltip.height() + 'px'
                        };
                        $tooltip.find('span.tooltip_arrow').addClass('tooltip_arrow_RB');
                        break;
                    case 'T'    :
                        properties = {
                            'left'  : e_l + e_w/2 - $tooltip.width()/2 + 'px',
                            'top'   : e_t + e_h + 'px'
                        };
                        $tooltip.find('span.tooltip_arrow').addClass('tooltip_arrow_T');
                        break;
                    case 'R'    :
                        properties = {
                            'left'  : e_l - $tooltip.width() + 'px',
                            'top'   : e_t + e_h/2 - $tooltip.height()/2 + 'px'
                        };
                        $tooltip.find('span.tooltip_arrow').addClass('tooltip_arrow_R');
                        break;
                    case 'B'    :
                        properties = {
                            'left'  : e_l + e_w/2 - $tooltip.width()/2 + 'px',
                            'top'   : e_t - $tooltip.height() + 'px'
                        };
                        $tooltip.find('span.tooltip_arrow').addClass('tooltip_arrow_B');
                        break;
                    case 'L'    :
                        properties = {
                            'left'  : e_l + e_w  + 'px',
                            'top'   : e_t + e_h/2 - $tooltip.height()/2 + 'px'
                        };
                        $tooltip.find('span.tooltip_arrow').addClass('tooltip_arrow_L');
                        break;
                }


                /*
                if the element is not in the viewport
                we scroll to it before displaying the tooltip
                 */
                var w_t = $(window).scrollTop();
                var w_b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
                //get the boundaries of the element + tooltip
                var b_t = parseFloat(properties.top,10);

                if(e_t < b_t)
                    b_t = e_t;

                var b_b = parseFloat(properties.top,10) + $tooltip.height();
                if((e_t + e_h) > b_b)
                    b_b = e_t + e_h;


                if((b_t < w_t || b_t > w_b) || (b_b < w_t || b_b > w_b)){
                    $('html, body').stop()
                    .animate({scrollTop: b_t}, 500, 'easeInOutExpo', function(){
                        //need to reset the timeout because of the animation delay
                        if(autoplay){
                            clearTimeout(showtime);
                            showtime = setTimeout(nextStep,step_config.time);
                        }
                        //show the new tooltip
                        $tooltip.css(properties).show();
                    });
                }
                else
                //show the new tooltip
                    $tooltip.css(properties).show();
            }

            function removeTooltip(){
                $('#tour_tooltip').remove();
            }

            function showControls(){
                /*
                we can restart or stop the tour,
                and also navigate through the steps
                 */
                var $tourcontrols  = '<div id="tourcontrols" class="tourcontrols">';
                $tourcontrols += '<p>First time here?</p>';
                $tourcontrols += '<span class="button" id="activatetour">Start the tour</span>';
                    if(!autoplay){
                        $tourcontrols += '<div class="nav"><span class="button" id="prevstep" style="display:none;">< Previous</span>';
                        $tourcontrols += '<span class="button" id="nextstep" style="display:none;">Next ></span></div>';
                    }
                    $tourcontrols += '<a id="restarttour" style="display:none;">Restart the tour</span>';
                    $tourcontrols += '<a id="endtour" style="display:none;">End the tour</a>';
                    $tourcontrols += '<span class="close" id="canceltour"></span>';
                $tourcontrols += '</div>';

                $('BODY').prepend($tourcontrols);
                $('#tourcontrols').animate({'right':'30px'},500);
            }

            function hideControls(){
                $('#tourcontrols').remove();
            }

            function showOverlay(){
                var $overlay    = '<div id="tour_overlay" class="overlay"></div>';
                $('BODY').prepend($overlay);
            }

            function hideOverlay(){
                $('#tour_overlay').remove();
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

---

Your fiddle has a js error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'easeInOutExpo'`

That suggests to me that you forgot to include some sort of [jQuery Easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).